# GRE 0568 #66: On whether or not exactly 2 right ideals give a non-commutative field (field except multiplication is not commutative)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, ideals

Algebra by Michael Ch11.3

Artin has different definitions of rings particularly that his rings are unital and commutative in both addition and multiplication. Therefore, ideals are neither right nor left, afaik. (*)

In the book, Artin proves that a commutative unital ring with exactly 2 ideals is a field. (*) For non-commutative unital rings, I would like to know what we get under certain circumstances eg a non-commutative field or [a division ring](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/331020/do-people-ever-study-non-commutative-fields). Edit: Apparently, non-commutative field isn't necessarily defined as a division ring or anything at all. **What I mean by non-commutative field** is that we have all the properties of fields except that multiplication is not commutative.

If a commutative unital ring with exactly 2 ideals is a field, then...

1. Is a non-commutative unital ring with exactly 2 right ideals a non-commutative field?
2. Is a non-commutative unital ring with exactly 2 left ideals a non-commutative field?
3. (Never mind this) Is a non-commutative unital ring with exactly 1 left ideal and exactly 1 right ideal a non-commutative field? (Never mind this)
4. Is a non-commutative unital ring with exactly 2 ideals a non-commutative field?
5. (Never mind this) Does a non-commutative unital ring with exactly 1 left ideal and exactly 1 right ideal have exactly 2 ideals? (Never mind this)

---

This is based on a GRE question:

> [image]

I mistakenly answered $D$ instead of $B$ because I forgot that Artin defines rings to be commutative.

It appears the answer to my first question is affirmative because of Ian Coley's solution (which I think forgets to say $r \ne 0$)

> [image]

I don't see how the answer to my second question would be different because $0$ and $R$ I guess are still left ideals.

---

(*)

Definition of ideals of a ring:

> [image]
>
> [image]

Prop 11.3.19(b) says a ring with exactly 2 ideals is a field:

> [image]

Comment: Clearly the question’s definition of a ring does not require it to be commutative, otherwise option (I) would be silly to include. And I would think that the solution you posted answers most of your questions.

Comment: @Joppy Thanks! I guess the solution answers 1 and 2 in affirmative, but I don't think Artin has left or right ideals at least in Ch11.1-11.3, so I don't immediately know, and it might be tiresome wheel reinventing if I try it out. Does the solution posted, in your opinion, answer questions 3-5 for someone whose knowledge of left and right ideals is currently limited to this GRE question?

Comment: It’s unclear how you want this question answered, since you are changing assumptions like commutative and unital throughout your post. A ring with exactly one ideal must be the zero ring, since $0$ and $R$ are always two-sided ideals, which answers 3 and 5.

Comment: @Joppy What do you mean? Are left ideals necessarily not right ideals and vice-versa? My questions explicitly say 'non-commutative'. As for unital, does this question assume unital? I guess so based on Ian Coley's solution. Wait you point out yourself [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2967070/) that the ring is unital. Soooo yeah unital non-commutative.

Comment: Question 66 starts by saying that the ring has a multiplicative identity. And no, in non-commutative rings, a left ideal may not be a right ideal. For example, consider the ring of 2x2 matrices over some field, then the matrices with zeros in the right column will be a left ideal but not a right ideal (or the other way around, I’m lazy)

Comment: @Joppy What? My question is if a left ideal is necessarily *not* a right ideal. I'm not asking if a left ideal is *necessarily* a right ideal.

Comment: Ah this is all getting quite confusing. Suffice to say, the answer to this question does not change whether or not the ring is commutative! If the ring *is* commutative, then right ideals are the same as two-sided ideals, but this does not change the answer! (But also, since (I) is an option, it is clear the question does not assume the ring is commutative). Have you come across a problem which *does* have a different answer if you assume things like unital or commutative for rings?

Comment: "Non-commutative field" is not a standard term. Presumably you mean "division ring" (aka "skew field"). For the answer to I, see the accepted answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/208066/fields-are-characterized-by-the-property-of-having-exactly-2-ideals

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fields are characterized by the property of having exactly 2 ideals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/208066/fields-are-characterized-by-the-property-of-having-exactly-2-ideals)

Comment: @symplectomorphic Oh man, what a stupid question I asked. I think you should voted to close as unclear rather than duplicate. Duplicate is only a slap on the wrist, which less than I deserve. Thanks! I edited.

Comment: @symplectomorphic What Bourbaki calls fields we would call division rings, so perhaps that terminology is still sticking around somewhere...

Comment: @BCLC I think your question is mostly fine, but just confusingly worded since you are changing assumptions throughout, for example you are posting definitions of ideals and rings and then asking if they are consistent with the rest of your post, which is confusing... I can write up a short answer to clarify the two-sided ideals and left/right ideals and division ring thing.

Comment: @Joppy Thank you very much for your brutally honest and helpful comments and upcoming answer! Better hurry because this question might be a dupe soon.

Comment: @Joppy Re: 'Have you come across a problem which does have a different answer if you assume things like unital or commutative for rings?' EXCELLENT QUESTION. I hope I can ask questions like yours. Hmmm...so far none. I guess I better have a second look. I was just wondering how we change Prop11.3.19b if rings are not commutative but still unital.

Comment: @symplectomorphic Actually, perhaps if this were a dupe of anything, then it would be of this: [Where does the proof for commutative rings break down in the non-commutative ring when showing only two ideals implies the ring is a field?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1074861) ?

Comment: @symplectomorphic Actually I did say in the first revision 'non-commutative field aka a division ring', though it wasn't in the title. Anyhoo I now clarified that hopefully.

Comment: [There are simple rings which are not commutative](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/606248/29335), and [here is why the proof that commutative simple rings are fields breaks down](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1074861/29335)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $R$ be a (perhaps non-commutative) nonzero ring with a unit. Then the following are equivalent:

1. $R$ is a division ring, i.e. every nonzero element has an inverse.
2. $R$ has precisely two left ideals.
3. $R$ has precisely two right ideals.

*Proof*:

- ($1 \implies 2$) If $I \neq \{0\}$ is a left ideal, then let $a \in I$ be a nonzero element. By the division ring assumption, $a^{-1} \in R$ exists, and $1 = a^{-1} a \in RI \subseteq I$ by the fact that $I$ is a left ideal. So $1 \in I$, and $I = R$.
- ($2 \implies 1$) Since $\{0\} \neq R$ are always ideals, for any nonzero $a \in R$, the left ideal $aR = R$. Hence there exists some $b \in R$ such that $ab = 1$.
- The proof of $(1 \iff 3)$ is identical to $(1 \iff 2)$.

We also have the following implication: if $R$ is a division ring, then $R$ has precisely two two-sided ideals. This follows readily from the above. But the converse implication is *not* true: if $R$ has precisely two two-sided ideals, it may not be a division ring. For example, [the matrix ring over a field has only two two-sided ideals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/362559/show-that-every-ideal-of-the-matrix-ring-m-nr-is-of-the-form-m-ni-where).

Finally, if $R$ is commutative, a left ideal is a right ideal is a two-sided ideal, and so everything above is equivalent.

Comment: Thanks a million, Joppy! ^-^ To clarify, a unital division ring is a field except multiplication is not commutative? That's what I think it says on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_ring#cite_note-1). What specifically are the answers to questions 1-5 please? 1 and 2 I guess are yes by your equivalence proof. 4 I guess is no by 'converse implication is not true', and 3 and 5 are actually wrong questions because for a non-commutative unital ring with exactly 1 right ideal and exactly 1 left ideal, such ideals are actually equal?

Comment: I'm not going to answer explicitly what 1-5 are, there is more than enough information in this post for you to figure them out. Also, keep in mind that if a ring has only one ideal, it must be the zero ring. And yes, a division ring is basically a field without the commutativity condition. Note that "unital division ring" and "division ring" must mean the same thing, since to define what an inverse is, you need to have a multiplicative unit.

Comment: Thanks Joppy! Ok wrong question. I mean, is it meaningless to say 'exactly 1 right ideal and exactly 1 left ideal' hoping that the non-commutative unital ring would have more than 1 (right or left) ideal?

Comment: A ring (perhaps non-unital, perhaps non-commutative) always has one left ideal, the zero ideal. Since $R$ itself is always a left ideal, if $R$ has only one left ideal, then $R = \{0\}$ is the zero ring. So if a ring has exactly one left ideal, it is the zero ring.